# iText choosing path where save PDF

Tags: java, swing, pdf, itext

I finally made my PDF file via iText but now I need for my SWING project to select the path of saving that PDF file by myself. not automaticly as it is normal via absolute path like:

```
 PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("C:\\ and my path ""));
```

but I want when I click on a button system ask me to the path where I can save the file (another folder, etc.) Just not the absolute path in program.
Thx for help ^^

Comment: You should go up to the little search box on this site and type in `swing file dialog`, then hit enter

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an iText question, but since you tagged it as an iText question, I'll give you an iText answer. Please check out [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups). This is a tool based on iText that allows you to look at a PDF file from the inside.

The code to open a file can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextrups/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/rups/io/FileChooserAction.java):

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setCurrentDirectory(dirOfYourChoice);
fc.setSelectedFile(fileOfYourChoice); 
fc.setFileFilter(filterOfYourChoice);
int okCancel = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
```

Look at the API docs of [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) for more info.

Comment: This is indeed an iText question.